# Error: Could not open types-file- while converting .osm file to .net.xml using netconvert

Tags: openstreetmap, sumo

I am using sumo v0.30.0 in ubuntu 16.04

I am trying to convert .osm file to .net.xml file using netconvert

xxx@xxx-H81M-S2VP:~/xxx/sumo-0.30.0/manhattan$ netconvert --osm-files manhattan.osm -o manhattan.net.xml

Error: Could not open types-file '/home/sumo-0.30.0/sumo//data/typemap/osmNetconvert.typ.xml'.
Quitting (on error).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your SUMO_HOME variable points to the wrong directory. Try something like `export SUMO_HOME=$HOME/sumo-0.30.0/sumo`. The directory should contain subdirectories named tools and data.

Comment: Thanks, it helped. There was some error in the path.